# Why link and text inside a div without explicit size are breaking?

Tags: html, css

I tried to have a tooltip which will have title and content, size should be auto. Meaning the title should not break and the content should fit accordingly.

In here the title and content are breaking why it is breaking? How to avoid this? can this be done without specifying height and width?

CODE

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    link
    <div class='arrow'></div>
<div class="left">
    <div class="tit"><a href="#">This is a big text link</a></div>
    <div class="content"> Hello this are contents so if the content is big</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .left{
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
      left:100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: -50%;
      padding:20px;
}
.wrap{
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;

}
.arrow
{
    border-bottom: 20px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 25px solid #008000;
    border-top: 20px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 0;
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L3QRH/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Mention the `.wrap` width to `100%`

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/6a67b/)**

```
.wrap{
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    width:100%;

}
```

Comment: THanks +1. If do this The link and arrow are not fitting exactly.the tooltip should be after the link

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to prevent a line-break, then probably the `white-space` attribute is what you are looking for.

just add `white-space: nowrap;` to the class where you want to prevent the break.

Comment: Thanks +1 for the info.I'll use this later as it not require now